# Cube with multiple texture

Tags: java, opengl, textures, jogl

I have a cube with single texture  -

```
public class TextureDemo implements GLEventListener, KeyListener {    
    private Texture texture;    
}
public void init(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable) {
    String filename="Picture1.jpg"; // the FileName to open
    texture=TextureIO.newTexture(new File( filename ),true);
}

public void display(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable) {
    texture.bind();
    gl.glBegin(GL.GL_QUADS);
    // Front Face
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(2f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(2f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    // Back Face
    ...

}
```

I trying to set multiple texture on the above cube  , means after the "Front Face"  , replace to another texture which will take effect on the other cube face's .

How could I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 2):

You bind a new texture. That tells GL that whatever we're about to draw will use that texture.

So, create new texture for a different JPG file, then bind it, then draw some vertices.

Comment: I tried with no success . can you supply code section please  ?

Comment: @URL87: glBindTexture works not within a glBegin/glEnd block. (You shouldn't be using glBegin/glEnd anyway. Use Vertex Arrays)